# How to change a particular image in ios using appearance proxy?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uiimageview

I am using theme concept in iOS.I am changing the background of each 
`UIViewController` for that i have used an `UIImageView` as background for all view controllers.Now on theme change i want to change the image but in this case other `UIImageView` in the view controller are also changed.So i want to know how can i change the particular image view using appearance proxy.

**Code for changing the appearance using proxy**

```
[[UIImageView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UpdateProfile class], nil] setImage:image];
```

Comment: this might help you: http://petersteinberger.com/blog/2013/uiappearance-for-custom-views/

Comment: I want to change the appearance of only one UIImageView in a single class. As of now it change the appearance of the all UIImageView.@T_77